# How to get same I'd data from many foreignkey field in same table?

Tags: python, django

I'm new in `Django` and I'm developing a coaching website, I want to store `studentID` and multiple `CourseId` through foreign key in student course table and catching data according to `studentID` and display student data and all courses which selected by students on 'HTML TABLE' page in single Column.

**Model.py**

```
class course_content(models.Model):
      course = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
      Code = models.CharField(max_length=50)

class student_admission(models.Model):
      Student = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
      Father = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
      Date = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
      Gender = models.CharField(max_length= 50)

class student_course(models.Model):
     Student_id= models.ForeignKey(student_admission,on_delete=None)
     Course_id = models.ForeignKey(course_content,on_delete=None)
```

**Views.py**

```
def savedata(request):
    student = request.POST.get("student")
    father = request.POST.get("father")
    date = request.POST.get("date")
    gender = request.POST.get("gender")
    c_id = request.POST.getlist("cid")
    obj = student_admission(Student=student,Father=father,Date=date,Gender=gender)

    obj.save()
    for id in c_id:
        obj2 = student_course(Student_id_id=obj.id,Course_id_id=id)
        obj2.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect(settings.BASEURL +'/home')


def table(request):
    data = student_course.objects.all().prefetch_related('Student_id','Course_id')
    unique_list = [] 
    for x in data:
        if x not in unique_list:
           unique_list.append(x) 
    d = {'data1' : unique_list}
    return render(request,"html/tables.html",d)
```

**Table.html**

```
        {% for c in data1 %}
        <tr>
        <td>{{c.Student_id.id}}</td>
        <td>{{c.Student_id.Student}}</td>
        <td>{{c.Student_id.Father}}</td>
        <td>{{c.Student_id.Date}}</td>
        <td>{{c.Course_id.course }}</td>
        <td>{{c.Student_id.Gender}}</td>
        <td><a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="../editid/{{item.id}}">Edit</a>&nbsp;<a type="button" class="btn btn-success" href="../deleteid/{{item.id}}">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

Comment: I think your model should be improved. The student should be the user model and it should connect with course with a f.k directly. Then you can simply add a query set or a for statement to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Make only 2 Models like this in models.py

```
class Course(models.Model):
      course = models.CharField(max_length= 100)
      code = models.CharField(max_length=50)


      def __str__(self):
          return self.course


  

GENDER = (
    ('M', 'M'),
    ('F', 'F'),
)
class Student(models.Model):
      name = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
      course  = models.ManyToManyField(Course)
      father = models.CharField(max_length= 50)
      date = models.DateField(max_length= 50)
      gender = models.CharField(max_length= 50, choices = GENDER)
       
      def __str__(self):
          return self.name
```

Now to find all the course taken by a student:
Let's say you have a student s = get_object_or_404(Student, id=1)

**all_courses = s.course_set.all()**

will contain each course taken by student of id=1.

You can iterate over all courses in template to print.

```
{% for c in all_courses %}

{{c}}

{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I want all selected course in one column on HTML Table like: ID =id ,student = student name , father = father name and course = all selected course

Comment: Through this all_courses = s.course_set.all() you will get all selected course in one column

Answer (score -1):

you can use a ManyToManyField instead of ForeignKey to achieve your goal.

```
Course_id = models.ManyToManyField(course_content)
```

Also, check out this link for detail information about ManyToManyField.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/